# Get a value from a object hasOwnProperty search

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm using NodeJS trying to get a value from a object search, this is my code:

```
var search = "key_13"

var object = {
  "group_1": {
    "key_11": "value_11",
    "key_12": "value_12",
    "key_13": "value_13"
  },
  "group_2": {
    "key_21": "value_21",
    "key_22": "value_22",
    "key_23": "value_23"
  },
  "group_3": {
    "key_31": "value_31",
    "key_32": "value_32",
    "key_33": "value_33"
  }
}

if (object.group_1.hasOwnProperty(search)) {
  console.log("group_1")
}
```

How can I get the value from the key `search` in the object? Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple. You can access the value of `search` key using `object.group_1[search]`.

You can try this -

```
var search = "key_13";

var object = {
  "group_1": {
    "key_11": "value_11",
    "key_12": "value_12",
    "key_13": "value_13"
  },
  "group_2": {
    "key_21": "value_21",
    "key_22": "value_22",
    "key_23": "value_23"
  },
  "group_3": {
    "key_31": "value_31",
    "key_32": "value_32",
    "key_33": "value_33"
  }
};

if (object.group_1.hasOwnProperty(search)) {
    console.log(object.group_1[search]); // <-- this will print the value in key `search`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse object using for..in loop. Then Again traverse the inner object and search the key. If found print the parent object name.

```js
var search = "key_13";
var object = {
  group_1: {
    key_11: "value_11",
    key_12: "value_12",
    key_13: "value_13",
  },
  group_2: {
    key_21: "value_21",
    key_22: "value_22",
    key_23: "value_23",
  },
  group_3: {
    key_31: "value_31",
    key_32: "value_32",
    key_33: "value_33",
  },
};

for (p in object) {
  for (q in object[p]) {
    if (q === search) {
      console.log(p);
    }
  }
}
```